# Building Dynamic fragments in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this Ecto query:

```
def sum(query) do
  from aggregate in query,
  select: %{
    ones: fragment("coalesce(sum(ones), 0)"),
    twos: fragment("coalesce(sum(twos), 0)"),
    threes: fragment("coalesce(sum(threes), 0)"),
    fours: fragment("coalesce(sum(fours), 0)"),
    fives: fragment("coalesce(sum(fives), 0)"),
    unanswered: fragment("coalesce(sum(unanswered), 0)"),
    n_size: fragment("coalesce(sum(n_size), 0)"),
    comment_count: fragment("coalesce(sum(comment_count), 0)")
  }
end
```

I am concerned about the duplication of the `fragment`, `coalesce` and `sum` on each line here. Is there a way that I can move that out to its own function and call it like this?

```
def sum(query) do
  from aggregate in query,
  select: %{
    ones: sum.("ones"),
    twos: sum.("twos"),
  ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot be done with a plain function as far as I know, but you can do this with a macro:

```
defmacro sum_or_zero(column) do
  quote do
    fragment(unquote("coalesce(sum(#{column}), 0)"))
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
def sum(query) do
  from aggregate in query,
    select: %{ id: sum_or_zero("id") }
end
```

With the above function and macro, the following code:

```
MyApp.User |> A.sum |> MyApp.Repo.one |> IO.inspect
```

prints:

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=1.9ms
SELECT coalesce(sum(id), 0) FROM "users" AS u0 []
%{id: 6}
```

---

I would suggest passing the column into `sum_or_zero` instead of a string though:

```
  defmacro sum_or_zero(column) do
    quote do
      fragment("coalesce(sum(?), 0)", unquote(column))
    end
  end

  def sum(query) do
    from aggregate in query,
      select: %{ id: sum_or_zero(aggregate.id) }
  end
```

This way the query will use the table name in the query:

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=1.9ms
SELECT coalesce(sum(u0."id"), 0) FROM "users" AS u0 []
%{id: 6}
```